# Does Saxon provide a way to sort returned nodes?

Tags: java, saxon

Does Saxon have a way to return nodes in sorted order where the "order" is defined by 1 or more nodes/attributes in the returned nodes?

In other words, the XPath query could be:

```
/Order/Dates/Date order by .
```

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, there are many ways! But you need to be a bit more precise about the requirements if you want a precise answer.

You could use XQuery:

```
for $x in /Order/Dates/Date order by $x return $x
```

If you've got Saxon, then there's no particular reason to want a solution that's pure XPath rather than XQuery, but XPath 3.0 does have some sorting ability through the fn:sort function:

```
sort(/Order/Dates/Date, function($date){ $date })
```

Except for the most trivial sort keys, however, fn:sort involves higher-order functions which requires Saxon-PE or higher.

And of course sorting is also possible using XSLT.

If you're generating the expression, I don't think there's much difference between generating the XQuery form:

```
for $e in /*/Employee 
order by $e/firstName, $e/LastName
return e
```

and the XPath version

```
sort(/*/Employee,
   function($e){$e/firstName, $e/lastName})
```

and there's very likely to be any noticeable performance difference. The XQuery version is a bit more flexible, for example in allowing descending order, choice of collations, handling of absent values, etc.

These are standard XPath/XQuery facilities so they are described in the W3C specifications. XQuery sorting has been there since 1.0 so it will be described in any book on XQuery; XPath sorting is new in XPath 3.1 so you won't find it in many books or online tutorials yet.

Comment: First off we do have the enterprise version of Saxon so that't not a problem. Our system presently is set up so users can enter "/Order/Dates/Date order by ." to get a list of nodes back in sorted order. At present we call Saxon to get the nodes in document order and then sort it ourselves.
If Saxon can do that, I'd prefer that. We would convert from our syntax to the above on the fly when calling the select. So 3 questions. Which approach is better/faster? Second, can it handle multiple sort nodes/attributes (ie LastName, FirstName), Third, where is the syntax documented? TIA.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if we can't use the XQuery approach (because of our license), then we're restricted to the XPath approach. And the XPath approach does no support combinations of ascending and descending sort criteria - correct?

Comment: And how do we call "sort(/*/Employee,
   function($e){$e/firstName, $e/lastName})" from the Saxon Java API?